# pandas collapse Series values into one value

Tags: python, pandas

How does one collapse a Series into one value? I tried `pd.concat()`.

```
  dict = {"Cities": ["Chicago", "Hong Kong", "London"], "People": ["John", "Mike", "Sue"]}
  df = pd.Dataframe.from_dict(dict)

        Cities People
  0    Chicago   John
  1  Hong Kong   Mike
  2     London    Sue
```

*** desired output: ***

```
"John Mike Sue"
```

Comment: Does `" ".join(df.People)` work?

Comment: yes it does- thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use string method [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html), apart from `' '.join(df.People)`

```
In [96]: df.People.str.cat(sep=' ')
Out[96]: 'John Mike Sue'
```

Comment: this was the function I was looking for but didn't find in the docs --- thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe `' '.join(series)` should do it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Cannot be named dict, as dict is a type.
dictionary = {"Cities": ["Chicago", "Hong Kong", "London"], "People": ["John", "Mike", "Sue"]}
print(' '.join(dictionary['People'])
```

You don't have to type the first line, as it is a comment.